# Caching a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, caching, uiwebview

I am very new to iphone development and i am trying to get a web view to cache onto the device so that it will sty there even when the application is closed and then reload the data when the application starts again. I would also like it to reload the data in the cache every 2 weeks.

Many Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: you probably don't want to cache the view, but the data (model)

Comment: well i need to cache the view as the one of the pages is a web view and gives a load of info, i would like this to be available offline and not use data every time it loads, but also be able to update it without having to pushing a update onto the app store

Comment: Sorry about that last comment (was really new to programming (still am)) and looking back at it i know i needed to cache the web page page not the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

through a lot of searching around and asking friends i managed to find the code and though that i would share it with everyone

**Objective-C**

```
- (void) cacheFile
{
    //Create the file/directory pointer for the storage of the cache.
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    self.dataPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cache.html"];

    //Check to see if a file exists a the location
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]) {
       //Code for customising when the cache reloads would go here.
    }
    else
    {
        //If no file exists write the html cache to it
        //Download and write to file
        NSURL *cacheUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"INSERT WEB URL HERE"];
        NSData *cacheUrlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:cacheUrl];
        [cacheUrlData writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES]; 
    }
//Run the load web view function.
[self loadWebView];
}


- (void) loadWebView
{
//Load up the web view from the cache.
[WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:dataPath]]];

}
```

**Swift 3**

```
func cacheFile() {
    //Create the file/directory pointer for the storage of the cache.
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    guard let dataPath = paths.first?.appending("cache.html") else {
        return
    }

    //Check to see if a file exists a the location
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dataPath) {
        //Code for customising when the cache reloads would go here.
    } else if let cacheUrl = URL(string: "INSERT WEB URL HERE") {
        //If no file exists write the html cache to it
        //Download and write to file
        do {
            let cacheUrlData = try Data(contentsOf: cacheUrl)
            try cacheUrlData.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: dataPath), options: Data.WritingOptions.atomic)
        } catch {
            print("Problem with cacheUrlData")
        }
    }

    //Run the load web view function.
    loadWebView(dataPath: dataPath)
}

func loadWebView(dataPath: String) {
    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: dataPath)))
}
```